# WordPress multiple content sections

Tags: php, wordpress

Alright I am completely lost on how to do this so I am just going to throw the question out there and hope somebody can help me in some way or another.

WordPress offers the option to create custom [Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) so I got the idea of pulling something out of my hat and creating a custom content section apart from the content section wordpress currently offers.

[image]

The website shown above is the only website I have been able to find which currently does this and is on a WordPress platform, as you can see they have the SoundCloud audio player pushed over to one side with the actual content placed to the other side creating that flawless look.

I guess the question here is how can I turn `<?php the_content(); ?>` into something completely custom pulling from a completely different form in the back end so the same information is not shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to achieve what you want.

1. [Shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)
2. [Custom page templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)
3. [Custom meta fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to store values like the soundcloud embed url, to afterwards use it in your code.
4. You can always also enter HTML in the page editor, but for obvious reasons not recommended.

Comment: Very nice, thank you for that fast answer this seems to do exactly what I want with the Custom Meta Fields.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) allow you to define a new type of content. It will have its own section in admin where you add and edit data separate from normal Wordpress posts. It can have its own templates allowing different layouts, and you can set up custom fields so that it can store different data.

I also recommend taking a look at the [Pods Framework](http://pods.io/). This plugin allows you to define custom content types very easily in the admin interface. You can set up all your fields and data types from there. All that's required then is to create the templates to make it look nice.

The nice thing about these approaches is that while the data is kept separate from standard Wordpress posts, you still have the same familiar UI, so it's easy for none-technical users to update the content.